# c++ file with no extension

Tags: c++, umfpack

I have a project that throw compilation errors, I have a file named "UmfPackSupport"  that is included in another file named "PoissonBlender.hpp" with the line:

```
#include "unsupported/Eigen/UmfPackSupport"
```

I then have an error in the line:

```
solve<double, UmfPackSupport>(A, b, u);
```

that says

```
'UmfPackSupport' was not declared in this scope
```

what is that file with no extension ??

Comment: Any text file with proper C++ inside it, can be included in C++ source files.

Comment: I don't think the extension matters in any way. Check if this file is really included, see of the `UmfPackSupport` is defined in that file, check its `namespace`, etc. Treat it just like a normal header.

Comment: And `UmfPackSupport` is probably in a `namespace <some-name> {}`.

Comment: Did you check this?
http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=93623

Comment: Etienne: actually I feel reading german when reading topics like these  ... thank you guys all your replies are convinient :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the file name. But you are using things in the wrong way. What version of Eigen are you using, because `UmfPackSupport` has been migrated to the supported modules in version 3.1

Comment: how could I find the eigen version ?

Comment: Note that current C++ usage is to have header files without extensions.